# If the A class's member function is changed, client binary of the A class need to be rebuild?

Tags: c++

1.A class is implemented in libA.so

```
class A
{
  A_fun();
  B_fun();
}
```

2.client use A class via libA.so

```
client{
  use A_fun();
}
```

In this situation,
If A class's member function is added C_fun(),

```
class A
{
  A_fun();
  B_fun();
  C_fun(); //added
}
```

As I know, If A_fun() parameter is changed, client have to rebuild.

But client is not use C_fun().

It this case, client binary need to be rebuild?

Comment: https://www.acodersjourney.com/20-abi-breaking-changes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is platform dependant. On most platforms adding a non-virtual member function to a class doesn't break the ABI. Generally you can make the following changes to a class without breaking the ABI:

1. Add non-virtual methods
2. Rename private methods and variables
3. Add static methods
4. Remove private methods
5. Remove private static methods
6. Add static member variables
7. Remove private static member variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

How can I know whether ABI is break or not in my platform?

And If I can not ensure that(ABI is not break in my platform),

Do I need to recompile client binary for safety?

Comment: If you only make the above changes you will be ok. You can use https://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/ to verify